# discord.py bot not responding in server

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents(guilds=True, messages=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


    ##Command to let you know bot is running
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')


    ##Quick reply command to let you know its working
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'hello':
        await message.channel.send('Hi!')
    await bot.process_commands(message)


bot.run(My_Token)
```

just trying to get the bot to respond to messages in the server. it works as intended in direct message. i also have all intents enabled.

(edit:I did have @bot.event just forgot to add it back when attempting to fix code)

(edit 2: the problem has been solved)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to add `@bot.event` before the on_message function?

Here is an example of a bot that i made while learning to use discord.ext. It should do you are describing

```
from discord.ext import commands


with open("TOKEN.txt", "r") as myfile:
    TOKEN = myfile.read()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")


linkList = [];

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} succesfully logged in!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'hello bot':
        print("hello")
        await message.channel.send(f'Hi {message.author}')
    if message.content == 'bye':
        await message.channel.send(f'Goodbye {message.author}')

    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: so i forgot to add it to this but i did have a @bot.event but forgot to add it again when changing code. there was also an error code i just couldnt figure out even after running it through an error checker ```discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.```